# Как добавить рекламу AdMob в проект libgdx на Android Studio

Tags: android

В интернетах есть инструкия, как добавить рекламу AdMob в проект libgdx, но в Eclipse. А я сделал игру в Android Studio, мне нужно добавить строчку (compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0') в gradle, но куда я не вставлял везде ошибка вылетает (вставлял в project(":android") {//dependencies {). В эклипсе вместо этого нужно было указать папку (google_play_services). вот мой градл.android:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'Boom-Boom'
        gdxVersion = '0.9.9'
        roboVMVersion = '0.0.13'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0' //тут ошибку выдает

    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')

    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Comment: это глобальный или локальный gradle?

в целом это не должно было вызвать проблем, в месте dependencies пишете `(compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0')` и делаете синхронизацию.

P.s gradle локальный

Answer (score -3, accepted):

вот тут показано, как правильно добавить AdMob в libgdx  [на Android Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cy8_8kB0Jc)

Answer (score 2):

Сейчас admob работает с [firebase](http://firebase.google.com) (на сколько мне известно, пару дней назад подключал именно так) подключите SDK по [этой](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) инструкции. И [инструкция](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start) по подключению admob.

**К примеру так:**

***Project-level build.gradle***

```
dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
```

***App-level build.gradle***

```
...
    dependencies {
           ...
           compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
           compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.0'
        }
...

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Нажимаете **Sync Now**, для синхронизации. И дальше как обычно.

И вообще посмотрите firebase, очень много чего может и все в одном месте.

Comment: firebase таким образом не подружить с libgdx

Comment: Если честно, не работал с libgdx, но не вижу разницы. Почему не подружить?

Comment: а вы почитайте инструкцию, как добавить адмоб в либгдх - там все по другому

Comment: [эта?](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx)

Comment: что там по другому?

Comment: project(":android") { сюда добавляете зависимости }

Comment: во-первых, я уже показал в своем исходнике комментарий, что в project(":android") { сюда добавляете зависимости } вылетает ошибка, а во-вторых, я уже ответил на свой вопрос. в-третьих, если вы не работали с libgdx, то ваши советы не помогут

Comment: Окей босс. Как будет угодно...

Comment: а чем лучше  admob через firebase? доходность увеличится?

Answer (score 2):

Я делал на идее, и не смог прикрутить адмоб самостоятельно. В итоге нашел готовые исходники для Android Studio, взял рабочий пример InterstitialExample и туда перевел весь свой код! И заработало.

Правда, пришлось помучиться, найти все упоминания чужого пакета, и переименовать на свой. И а-студия зверски тормозит. Ну да ладно, [Вот он, проект на ГитХабе =)](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples)